# load balancing for tomcat in aws instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, load-balancing, elastic-load-balancer

We are running many tomcat instances in t2.small aws. We are planning to configure load balancer for whole t2.small instance. Please help me how to do configure in AWS Load balancer for the intances.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring an ELB is straight forward in AWS.

Choose which ELB you want (Application or Classic).  The AWS [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/) shows you how to configure the ALB.

The only reason I can think of to use a classic load balancer is if you need to use Layer 4 network traffic (Windows Authentication for example).

Setting up an ELB does not impact your existing access, so you can set one up and test it with the Amazon DNS name and add your instances to it, setup the health check, etc in advance before switching your CNAME over to point to the ELB.

You also need to ensure your ELB can talk to a IGW (providing it's for public access) so put it in a subnet that has 0.0.0.0/0 to your igw-xxxxxx.  Finally, your security groups need to allow access in from the ELB.

If there is something specific you are unsure of let me know, but AWS provide excellent documentation on ELB's.